# Почему не рабает api в gradle так как ожидается?

Tags: android, gradle, lib, android-library, зависимости

Я создал Android lib в которой использую `ArCore` native (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/enable-arcore)

Проблема в том, что когда я собираю свою библиотеку и имплементирую ее в проекте, то получаю ошибку в этой строке

> CHECK(ArCoreApk_requestInstall(env, activity, user_requested_install, &install_status) == AR_SUCCESS);

Это своего рода `assert` который выполняет проверку. Так вот проблема решается следующим образом, мне нужно в `gradle` своего проекта в блоке `dependency` продублировать вот эту строку из `gradle` самой либы

```
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'
```

И тут впрос, зачем нужно указывать эту строку в градле проекта если

1. она уже указана в библиотеке
2. сама зависимость не испольуется в проекте, а только в библиотеке

Я нашел, вот такой ответ на SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574/5709159 где говориться о том, что если есть зависимости в вашей либе которые будут использованы в проекте в котором эта либа будет имплементирована, то для того, чтоб не дублировать зависимости в gradle либы нужно эти зависимости указывать не с `implementation`, а с `api` ключевым словом...

В любом случае я попробовал в своей либе вместо `implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'` написать `api 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'`, собрал либу, развернул ее в проекте, но все равно та же ошибка.

Что делаю не так?

**EDIT**

Если в строке подключения либы(модуля) к своему проекту добавляю `{ transitive = true }` , то есть в гредле получается вот так

```
implementation project(path: ':libplayer'){ transitive = true }
```

то получаю вот такую ошибку

> Could not find method project() for arguments [{path=:libplayer},
>
> build_6azrak32apltlq5242h8zt6ol$_run_closure2$_closure7@4c829ee1] on object of
>
> type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `{ transitive = true }` к строке подключения библиотеки. Т.е. должно получиться `implementation ('LIB_MODULE_DEP') { transitive = true }`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб получаю ошибку. Добавил в вопрос

Comment: У меня вот так вот нормально подключалось: `implementation project(':libplayer')`, т.е. без `path: ` - попробуйте так)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не понял, то есть просто удалить слово `path` ? Мне кажется `path` тут не имеет никакой роли, просто для понимания так сказать... В любом случае я попробовал удалить `path` не работает, попробовал добавить `{transitive = true }`  тоже не работает...

Comment: Других идей у меня нет(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а вот, что насчет этого думаете https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050961/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: Если я правильно понял - то это невозможно. Вместе с либой в проект попадают всё исходники оной. Иначе оно просто компилиться не будет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб странно. Но если эти классы используются только внутри либы... и снаружи они не нужны ... ну ладно