# Как сделать класс видимым только внутри библиотеки?

Tags: android

Есть вот такая структура моей либы

```
main->java->MyInterface.java
main->java->foo->FirstClass.java (наследует от MyInterface.java)
main->java->boo->SecondClass.java (наследует от MyInterface.java)
```

Проблема в том, что когда я собираю либу и имплементирую ее в другом проекте, то я без проблем могу обратиться к `MyInterface.java`, так как его видно для проекта. Я не хочу, чтоб пользователь либы вообще знал, что такой интерфейс существует.

P.S. Интерфейс `MyInterface.java` я взял только для примера это может быть куча других классов которые используются либой, но я не хочу, чтоб юзер вообще о них знал. Я даю ему определенный API и ему не нужно знать о всем остальном и путаться в этом.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Возможно это то что вы ищите: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588239/7609373